# How do I deploy a Django website with cPanel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my first Django application via my GoDaddy cPanel. I created my application in a virtual environment, but I'm confused as to which fields in cPanel I should be filling out, and with what values:

```
1. Application Root
2. Application URL
3. Application start up file (I know this should be manage.py. How should I add in it? Is it like local_disk/new_folder/project/manage.py?
4. Application entry point
5. Passenger log file
```

Comment: I don't use GoDaddy so not sure about most of this, but "i know this is manage .py" [is wrong](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver): "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)"

Comment: Tweaked title and body of question to be more understandable (spelling, grammar).

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Application Root:
```

this is the file system directory where the django app is installed (eg: /home/user123/django_app_dir)

```
2. Application URL:
```

define the url you will call to run the application (eg: www.website.com/app)

```
3. Application start up file:
```

it's not manage.py. This is the entry point of the application. You must pass a wsgi file (eg: passenger_wsgi.py). This file should be created by cPanel. If not create it by yourself inside `Application Root` dir

```
4. Application entry point
```

use `application`

As result a virtualenv is created in `Application Root` dir. Now you can perform the remaining deploy activities, for example:

- pip upgrade
- pip requirements
- source code by GIT clone or other means
- update env settings for DB connection
- set `DEBUG=False`
- add ALLOWED_HOSTS
- etc.

The `passenger_wsgi.py` file should be in the `Application Root` dir together with your app `wsgy.py` file

remove all content in passenger_wsgi.py and add a single line `from <your_app>.wsgi import application`